# Use the data from 1st JSON and convert it to a variable and use that variable to call a 2nd JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new here but I have a problem and need your help, so in my code I called a JSON file.

```
var data = {};
var spectator;
var tmp = [];
var IDcatcher =[];
var summonerID = [];
$.getJSON(getUrl, function(data) {
            tmp = data;

            $.each(tmp, function(key){
                for (IDcatcher in tmp) {}
                        
                });
            summonerID = tmp[IDcatcher].id;
        });
```

so this gives me the ID from the JSON which is stored in summonerID variable now I want to use this variable to complete the URL to get the 2nd JSON so.

```
var spectatorUrl = "link" + summonerID;
```

Now get the 2nd JSON

```
var Charcatcher =[];
var CharID = [];
$.getJSON(spectatorUrl, function(data) {
        tmp = data;

        $.each(tmp, function(key){
            for (Charcatcher in tmp) {}

            });
        CharID = tmp[Charcatcher].id;
    });
```

My problem is the 2nd JSON doesn't run, it doesn't get anything and returns nothing (obviously).

Help?
I can't run 2 JSONs at different times? If so how can I do it or change it?

Comment: **EDIT** I tried called both at the same time but problem is I need 1 to get the other so they would never finish check if sucessed.

Comment: Variabell lool sorry about that title

Comment: Are you using the two `.getJSON()`s successively, independent of one another?

Comment: Yes I am they are 2 diferent getJson

Comment: JS is asynchronous, meaning if you've got an AJAX request in your code, JS will send off that request, but will not wait for it to finish and instead keep executing the code **after** the AJAX request. I suspect this is why your `summonerID` returns `undefined`. To solve this, either put the second `$.getJSON()` inside the first one, so that `summonerID` will be available to it, or use Promises.

Comment: So I can put the 2nd Json inside my first Json ? How ? I mean how those it work ? I dont have any Ajax in my code.

Comment: Check out my answer. Also, `$.getJSON()` is just the jQuery shorthand for an AJAX request with a JSON response - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript, if you have an AJAX request with a callback and some code following the request, JS will fire off the AJAX request and will continue with the rest of the code. It won't wait for the result of the AJAX request to return.

Here's a simple demo -

```js
function first() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("1");
  }, 2000);
  
  console.log("2");
};

first();
```

Look at the order of the `console.log` statements in the code, and then check the actual order in the console.

To solve your original problem, you can nest a `$.getJSON()` inside the first one, this will ensure that `summonerID` is available when you fire off the second AJAX request.

```
$.getJSON(getUrl, function(data) {
            tmp = data;

            $.each(tmp, function(key){
                for (IDcatcher in tmp) {}

                });
            summonerID = tmp[IDcatcher].id;

            // second AJAX request
            var spectatorUrl = "link" + summonerID;
            $.getJSON(spectatorUrl, function(data) {
               // logic
            });

        });
```